# Importing Numpy increases the execution time of the first iteration in timeit.repeat

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, benchmarking

Using [`timeit.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/timeit.html#timeit.repeat) to measure the execution time of some expressions, I realized that the first iteration takes significantly longer if I imported `numpy` beforehand. Consider the following example:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import timeit
import numpy as np  # comment this line

results = timeit.repeat(
    "d['a']",
    setup="d = dict(zip('abc', '123'))",
    repeat=5, number=10**6
)
print(['{:.2e}'.format(x) for x in results])
```

I obtain the following results:

```
['5.38e-02', '2.72e-02', '2.70e-02', '2.68e-02', '2.70e-02']
```

The first iteration took significantly longer than the remaining ones (I verified this pattern by running the code multiple times).

Now when commenting out the `import numpy as np` line in the above code, then the timing results change as follows:

```
['2.73e-02', '2.71e-02', '2.65e-02', '2.68e-02', '2.66e-02']
```

Here the execution time of the first iteration is comparable to the others.

This behavior doesn't occur for Python 3.8 where I obtain similar timings, no matter if Numpy has been imported or not:

```
['2.64e-02', '2.89e-02', '2.65e-02', '2.63e-02', '2.63e-02']  # with 'import numpy'
['2.63e-02', '2.56e-02', '2.52e-02', '2.50e-02', '2.51e-02']  # without 'import numpy'
```

What causes this increase in execution time in conjunction with `import numpy` for Python 2.7?

---

Detailed version information:

- Python 2.7.12: `numpy==1.14.0`
- Python 3.8.1: `numpy==1.18.1`